# Hibernate many-to-many query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I need to do this query with hibernate
SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM objectif AS ob, objectifs_intervenants AS oi
WHERE ob.collaborateurId =2
AND ob.objectifId = oi.objectifId
AND oi.personneId =1
```

Ojectif class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "objectifId")
private int objectifId;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "objectifs")
private List<Intervenant> intervenants;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "collaborateurId")
private Collaborateur collaborateur;
```

Intervenant class

```
    @Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("intervenant")
public class Intervenant extends Personne 
{
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="objectifs_intervenants", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "personneId")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "objectifId")})
    private List<Objectif> objectifs;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I tiried to do it but every time I have a different esult for what i want I can't do it

Comment: Can you show the `Intervenant` class?

Comment: Show both the classes

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select ob from Objectif ob join Intervenant i
where ob.collaborateur.collaborateurId = :collaborateurId
and i.personneId = :personneId
```

This will return a list of `Objectif` objects and you can use `getIntervenants()` to get the additional info about intervenants that you had in your SQL query.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Do you get an error message? Or you don't get the expected results?